# React native - 3 components on the same row instead of vertically stacked

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-application

I'm practicing with React Native: in this list every entry returned for my database is composed by 3 items:

[image: How it looks now]

Now I want my screen to look like this:

[image]

My code is:

```
  <ListItem bottomDivider>
    <ListItem.Content style={{textAlign:'left'}}>
      <ListItem.Title>{item.title}</ListItem.Title>
      <ListItem.Subtitle
        style={{color: '#9D7463'}}>
        <Image
          style={{ alignSelf: "center", borderRadius: 50 }}
          source={{ uri: item.probability, width: 48, height: 48 }}
        />
      </ListItem.Subtitle>
      <ListItem.Subtitle
        style={{color: '#000', textTransform: 'uppercase'}}>
        {item.country_id}
      </ListItem.Subtitle>
      <Button
        buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: primaryColor, padding: 9, textAlign: "right"}}
        title="Follow"
        onPress={() => alert(item.id_user)}
      />
    </ListItem.Content>
  </ListItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `flexDirection` to `row`. Notice that [this is different from the web](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox):

> Flexbox works the same way in React Native as it does in CSS on the web, with a few exceptions. The defaults are different, with flexDirection defaulting to column instead of row

Thus, changing the flexDirection to row of the parent view, and setting `flex:1` for each child, should solve the issue.

```js
<ListItem.Content style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
<ListItem.Subtitle
        style={{color: '#9D7463', flex: 1}}>
        <Image
          style={{ alignSelf: "center", borderRadius: 50 }}
          source={{ uri: item.probability, width: 48, height: 48 }}
        />
      </ListItem.Subtitle>
      <ListItem.Subtitle
        style={{color: '#000', textTransform: 'uppercase', flex: 1}}>
        {item.country_id}
      </ListItem.Subtitle>
      <Button
        buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: primaryColor, padding: 9, textAlign: "right", flex: 1}}
        title="Follow"
        onPress={() => alert(item.id_user)}
      />
</ListItem.Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this component you can use flexbox

`<ListItem.Content style={{width: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>`

Comment: Thanks, but now everything is centered but vertically stacked; I've also removed 'alignSelf: "center"' from the image

Comment: Check my edit @gigapico00